# Notepad ++, Undo before Save not possible

Tags: notepad++, undo

After upgrading from Notepad++ 6.4.2 to 7.4.2 I'm not able to undo saved changes, as I was before with an earlier version.

Do you know if there's a setting to enable that behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't see one in any of the Preferences pages. Undo after save works just fine for me, as @Ogre55 said in the answer below.

Comment: I've reinstalled 6.4.2 earlier before I've been able to check out the suggested solution. When I've opened the 7.4.2 today, it was working. 
Not even rebooted before... confused, but happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am running notepad++ version 7.4.2 and the undo button as well as the keyboard shortcut work after a save.

open your file> make an edit>CTRL+S or click the save button>CTRL+Z or the undo button will remove the last edit.

you may have a plugin causing issues.  try starting notepad++ with the -noplugin switch